# MariaDB is not running, but PID file exists

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have an issue with MySQL. Although it looks like MySQL is able to start on my server:

```
service mysql start
Starting MariaDB.190930 03:56:09 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysqld.log'.
190930 03:56:09 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
..                                                         [  OK  ]
```

But when I am running:

```
service mysql status
MariaDB is not running, but PID file exists                [FAILED]
```

I tried:

- `rm -rf /var/lock/subsys/mysql`
- removed the pid
- removed `mysql.sock`

None of those helped me.

I know there are many threads regarding the topic but those didn’t help me.

I don’t see log errors in the MySQL log files:

```
190930  3:56:11 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
190930  3:56:11 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
190930  3:56:11 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.62-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
```

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue and I found a workaround. In my case I'm using the mysql.server startscript, installed through homebrew. In my case if I start the server using mysql.server start, it's working fine either. But using status or stop won't work with the same exception as yours. The fix is to use the parameter --user. 
Eg. `mysql.server status --user=[my_current_user]`.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I was facing errors when trying to run MariaDB server's status and stop commands.
`ERROR! MariaDB is not running, but PID file exists`

On Mac OS Big Sur with brew MariaDB 10.4, the following methods fixed the issue:

1. Start the server by running command:

`sudo mysql.server start`

2. Then, get the status by running command:
   `sudo mysql.server status --user=root`
3. And, stop the server by running command:
   `sudo mysql.server status --user=root`